# Cannot read handleEvent of undefined with Cordova on Android only

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, backbone.js

I'm trying to build an Cordova app using Backbone.js and underscore.js for templates.

When I upload my .zip to the Phonegap Cloud build Everything builds without errors inside the log file. The IOS version works without any hassle the Android version runs but the screen stays white.

When running the app on a physical device and checking it via `chrome://inspect` I see the following error:

[image: Console error]

My config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "app.appname.appname"
        version   = "0.2.0">
    <name>Appname</name>

    <description>
        Lorem ipsum
    </description>

    <author href="http://www.appname.nl" email="appname@appname.nl">
        Appname
    </author>

    <access origin="*"/>

    <!-- Which platforms to build for -->
    <gap:platform name="ios" />
    <gap:platform name="android" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git" />


    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"/>

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device" />

    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" spec="~1.8.0">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="xxx" />
    </plugin>


    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>

    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>

    <feature name="StatusBar">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
    </feature>

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />

    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
    <preference name="orientation"      value="portrait" />
    <preference name="target-device"    value="handset" />
    <preference name="fullscreen"       value="false" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />

    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"  value="true" />

    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />

    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />

    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="14" />

    <icon src="icon.png" />

    <platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />

        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="splash/android/drawable-land-ldpi/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="splash/android/drawable-land-mdpi/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="splash/android/drawable-land-hdpi/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="splash/android/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="splash/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi/screen-xxhdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="splash/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi/screen-xxxhdpi-landscape.png" />

        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="splash/android/drawable-port-ldpi/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="splash/android/drawable-port-mdpi/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="splash/android/drawable-port-hdpi/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="splash/android/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="splash/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi/screen-xxhdpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="splash/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi/screen-xxxhdpi-portrait.png" />
    </platform>

    <platform name="ios">
        <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="icons/ios/Icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />

        <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="splash/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="splash/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="splash/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="splash/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="splash/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>

</widget>
```

My zip folder structure:

```
www
- config.xml
- fonts
    - fontA.svg
    - fontA.woff
    - ...
- icons
    - android
       - drawable-hdpi-icon.png 
       - ...
    - ios
        - Icon-60@2x.png
        - ...
- images
    - loader.gif
    - ...
- scripts
    - main.min.js
    - vendor.min.js
    - vendor
        - modernizr.js
- splash
    - android
        - drawable-land-hdpi
            - screen-hdpi-landscape.png
        - ...
    - ios
        - Default-568h@2x~iphone.png
        - ...
- styles
    - main.min.css
    - vendor.min.css
```

Comment: Find method handleEvent in code. So you will define the object. I have a little experince with cordova framework but often the mistake appear when dom is not loaded at all. So check methods require document loaded

Comment: Without a [mcve], we can only guess.

Comment: What does your .zip file structure look like?

Comment: @KerriShotts I updated my question with the .zip file structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phonegap Error - "Cannot read property 'capture' of undefined" on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657553/phonegap-error-cannot-read-property-capture-of-undefined-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

I guess for event listener you immediately executed the function instead putting handler.

I can reproduce your problem with the code

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready',appStart(),false));
```

The correct code should be

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready',function(){appStart()},false));
```