# phonegap version naming conventions 1.0.0 vs 1.5.0 difference

Tags: android, iphone, blackberry, cordova

I'm working with phonegap Version 1.5.0. In this version the cordova.js file is different for different platforms, but the name is the same.

However, in phonegap version 1.0.0 the naming conventions are:
phonegap-android-1.0.0.js for android development and
phonegap-iphone-1.0.0.js for iPhone development.

I want complete platform independent development using phonegap. For this reason I want to know this.

I found an answer: [deviceready won't fire in Phonegap on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166954/deviceready-wont-fire-in-phonegap-on-android/7274154#7274154)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS file is different for each platform. You cannot use the same one across different platforms.